# Problems with Io Addons under Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, iolanguage

Has anybody managed to use `Io` addons like `Regex` or `OpenGL` under `Cygwin` on `Windows 7 32 bit`?

Notes:

- If it happen to be an `ASLR` issue, I want to keep `ASLR` enabled, so I did not test with it turned off.
- My `Cygwin` is a newer one, but not neccessarily bleading edge (`gcc (GCC) 4.3.4 20090804 (release) 1`)

The full story:

At my side I need some tweaks to compile and run `Io` under `Cygwin`.  To see my build process, minor patches and final tweaks to make the DLLs available to `Cygwin` see http://permalink.de/tino/iocyg

My OS is `Windows 7 starter 32 bit`, so `ASLR` is enabled.  This here is about builds under `Cygwin`, not `MinGW`, as under `MinGW` the `Regex` addon does not compile anyway due to missing `pcre` lib by default.

Under Cygwin I did not manage to use some Addons like `Regex` or `OpenGL` yet because of following error (note that `Cygwin` looks for `DLL`s in the search `PATH`, so I must add the lib to it, hence the `env`):

```
$ env PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/lib" io
Io 20090105
Io> Regex
==>  Regex_0xcd1788:
   [output skipped]
Io> "e" matchesRegex("." asRegex)
IoState error: missing proto 0x52128c
IoState_protoWithInitFunction() Error: missing proto
```

Googling for this error I found some posts relating to the fact, that `Io` uses the function pointer as hash to set the `proto`.  This address might change in a `DLL` situation so the hash breaks.  However looking into the code of `iovm/source/IoState.c` I am not able to understand if this really is the source of the problem or not (yet).

Going deeper into this:

```
Io> "a" matchesOfRegex("o") anchored
==> nil
Io> "a" matchesOfRegex(".") anchored
IoState error: missing proto 0x1983128c
IoState_protoWithInitFunction() Error: missing proto
```

This can be tracked down to the use of `Range` addon in function `IoRegexMatches_searchFrom_withOptions_` from `Regex/source/IoRegexMatches.c`.  And here I am currently stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Regex gave me problems until I installed [pcre](http://www.pcre.org/).

Fix:

1. Install pcre.
2. Recompile Io.